# How do I return relationship properties (Neo4j + Spring data)?

Tags: java, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

## Project Details

I am following along with these docs [Spring Data Neo4j](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) using Kotlin and I am struggling to return the relationship from a repository query:

**Database layout**

I have a `User` node and an `Skill` node with the following relationship:

[image]

**Entities**

Skill

```
@Node
data class Skill(
        @Id
        val uid: UUID,

        val title: String,
) {

    constructor(title: String) : this(UidGenerator.makeOne(), title)

}
```

User

```
@Node
data class User(
        @Id
        var uid: UUID,

        @Relationship(type = "DEMONSTRATES")
        val demonstrates: List<Demonstrates>,

        val firstName: String,
        val lastName: String,
) {

    constructor(demonstrates: List<Demonstrates>, firstName: String, lastName: String)
            : this(UidGenerator.makeOne(), demonstrates, firstName, lastName)

}
```

**Relationship Properties**

```
@RelationshipProperties
data class Demonstrates(
        @TargetNode
        val skill: Skill,

        val rating: Int,
)
```

## The Problem I am having

When I inject the following repository and call the `getDemonstrationList` I am getting the error that follows.

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository : Neo4jRepository<Skill, UUID> {

    @Query("""
        MATCH (:User)-[d:DEMONSTRATES]->(:Skill) RETURN d
    """)
    fun getDemonstrationList(): List<Demonstrates>

}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.NoRootNodeMappingException: Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside Record<{d: relationship<4>}> for org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentEntity@750a04ec
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jEntityConverter.read(DefaultNeo4jEntityConverter.java:106) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jEntityConverter.read(DefaultNeo4jEntityConverter.java:67) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.Schema.lambda$getRequiredMappingFunctionFor$0(Schema.java:96) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.Neo4jQuerySupport.lambda$getMappingFunction$0(Neo4jQuerySupport.java:105) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.PreparedQuery$AggregatingMappingFunction.apply(PreparedQuery.java:218) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.PreparedQuery$AggregatingMappingFunction.apply(PreparedQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DelegatingMappingFunctionWithNullCheck.apply(DelegatingMappingFunctionWithNullCheck.java:45) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DelegatingMappingFunctionWithNullCheck.apply(DelegatingMappingFunctionWithNullCheck.java:35) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.lambda$partialMappingFunction$0(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:325) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.all(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:312) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate$DefaultExecutableQuery.getResults(Neo4jTemplate.java:575) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.Neo4jQueryExecution$DefaultQueryExecution.execute(Neo4jQueryExecution.java:51) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractNeo4jQuery.execute(AbstractNeo4jQuery.java:85) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.getDemonstrationIds(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ntr.neo4j.Neo4jApplication.run(Neo4jApplication.kt:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

## My question

I am pretty new to Kotlin and Neo4j but I do understand the Spring framework. From what I understand, the repository is not able to workout that it needs to create a `Demonstrates` instance list out of the result of my query. I am interested in getting the `rating` property off the relationship but the tutorial is not really clear on how I can do that. Please let me know what I am missing in order to get my query to return a list of `Demonstrates`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Spring Data Neo4j 6, relationship cannot be top-level entities anymore.

As a consequence, your repository methods must return `Skill`, `SomeCollection<Skill>` (where `SomeCollection` can be a `List`, `Set`, `Flux`, `Page` etc).
You can also return projections based on `Skill`, but not `@RelationshipProperties`-annotated classes.

Answer (score 0):

As of now this works for me (with the properly annotated Domaintypes) using Spring-Boot 2.7.3 with Java, Neo4J and Webflux Starters. I didn't try this with non-reactive starters though.

```
public interface YourRelationDomainTypeRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<YourRelationDomainType, Long> {
    
        @Query("MATCH (u:NodeLabel1 {name: $userName})-[r:Relation]->(m:NodeLabel2) RETURN properties(r)")
        Flux<YourRelationDomainType> findPropertiesByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
    }
```